# How to insert in a std::list using iterator?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl

How to insert something in a list using its iterator? for example, I have a list of objects `myobj` where `myobj` contains another `list<int>`.

```
class myobj {
    //other data goes here
    list<int> l;
};
list <myobj> x;
```

Suppose I want to call the `insert()` function for the list in the nth element of `x`, I'll do something like

```
list<myobj>::iterator itr = x.begin();
std::advance(itr,n);
itr->insert(n); //It gives a compilation error.
```

I tried to learn `insert_iterator` but most of the examples I got were used with `copy()` function but here I want to call the `insert()` function of the list inside `myobj`.

Comment: The compiler should be choking on your use of a `list<int>` iterator on a `list<myObj>` list.

Comment: Use `std::advance` to position the iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `operator +=()` defined for std::list iterators. To advance your iterator use `std::advance`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

```
auto iter = x.begin();
std::advance(iter,n);
```

Keep in mind that you want to be certain your list is large enough for the iteration you are trying to perform.

To access the contents:

```
iter->l.insert(n);
```

When using an iterator, the '.' operator returns methods held by the iterator. If you dereference the iterator, `(*iter).` or use the `operator ->()` You should get access to the methods held by the object in your list.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's not what I am trying to do. 
I have a list `list<myobj> = x` and I don't want to insert into `x` but into the list contained at `nth` element of `x`.

Comment: @Anon Saw that after I reread your post. Edited to address that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot :)

Comment: There is `operator+=` for *some* iterators---only those of the random access iterator category, which `std::list<T>::iterator` is not, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Brian Thank you sir. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The call you want is `l.insert(iter, value);`

That inserts the object named `value` into the list `l` at the position pointed to by `iter`.